# What does the e => new EmployeeSummary { Employee = e } means?

Tags: c#

My friend gave me this code and I tried to understand what it does.

I understand that the function returns overall number of pending work tickets for all employees in the repository, but there is a single line of code that I did not understand and it's the line of:

```
var employees = employeeRepository.All.Select(e => new EmployeeSummary { Employee = e }).ToList();
```

I understand that in the end it makes a list of an employees but the `e=> new EmployeeSymmary` I do not understand

Please anyone can help?

The code:

```
public int GetTicketsForEmployees()
{
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
    ServiceTicketsRepository serviceTicketRepository = new ServiceTicketRepository();
    
    int ticketscount = 0;
    var employees = employeeRepository.All.Select(e => new EmployeeSummary { Employee = e }).ToList();

    foreach (var employee in employees) {
        var tickets = serviceTicketRepository.AllIncluding(t => t.Customer).Where(t => t.AssignedToID ==employee.Employee.ID).ToList();
        ticketscount += tickets.Count();
    }

    return ticketscount;
}
```

Comment: Search the internet for LINQ. [MSDN Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: Also your code formatting is super wonky

Comment: It means "a function that takes a parameter (let's call it `e`), and returns a `new EmployeeSummary()` (with its `Employee` property set to `e`)".

Answer (score 3):

`Select` is a projection. It maps the elements from the input to new values, using a function that you pass in. The `e => new EmployeeSummary` is a shorthand function syntax (called an "arrow function" or "lambda expression").

In this case, it is creating a new EmployeeSummary object for each Employee, and assigning the Employee (the "e" parameter) to the EmployeeSummary.Employee property.

`ToList` is called at the end because Select (like most LINQ operators) returns an `IEnumerable`, which can be "foreach"ed over, but very little else. In order to access the `.Count` or an element at an index (`list[0]`), the results must first be buffered into a list.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at lambda expressions, and object initializers, that should answer most of your questions :)

Lambda expressions:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Object initializers:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx